# help in use of ITAPI3 api

Tags: c#, call, modem, tapi

My problem is related to the use of ITAPI3. I am trying to build simple app that could call another number using modem connected to pc and a telephone line.
Platform is C# (new at this language)
In one of the post from 
[ITAPI3 Sending and Receiving Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6345310/itapi3-sending-and-recieving-data)

I could not figure out the use of the first line of the code. I get error in that line.

```
var handleArray = callForData.GetID("comm/datamodem");
```

Error is : callForData doesnot exists in current context also the "_dataTransferOutFileStream" has the same error.
What might be the problem? Is this due to missing library?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`callForData` was the variable name for a object of type `TCall`.

I have a working application that successfully sends and receives data as a datamodem. If you would like help with your application feel free to PM me.  Especially since that post was originally mine :)

Comment: no way to PM you. I wonder if it is legal to post my email. Can you help me in any other way?

Comment: c,h,r,i,s.m,c,n,e,a,r@spx.com  remove the commas.

Comment: I tried to send you mail in the email address. The mail failed to send. It says no such user.